# ORA-06550: Wrong number or type of arguments error when calling a function inside an oracle package in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, plsql

I have a function inside an oracle package called TEST in an Oracle 10g database

```sql
FUNCTION GetEname(P_ename IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
retVal VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
retVal := SUBSTR(P_ename, 3, INSTR(P_ename, ':', 1, 2) - 3);

RETURN RetVal;

END GetEntDefIEIDFromEname;
```

I have created an ASP.net page and I have the following code in the page_load:

```
String strResult = "";
        try
        {   
            oracleConn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleDatabase"].ConnectionString;
            oracleConn.Open();
            OracleCommand orclCmnd = new OracleCommand();
            orclCmnd.Connection = oracleConn;
            orclCmnd.CommandText = "TEST.GetEname";
            orclCmnd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            OracleParameter ename = new OracleParameter();
            ename.ParameterName = "ename";
            ename.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            ename.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            ename.Value = "0:490330";
            orclCmnd.Parameters.Add(ename);

            strResult = (String)orclCmnd.ExecuteOracleScalar();

            oracleConn.Close();
            oracleConn.Dispose();

            lbl1.Text = "Result of  " + strResult;
        }                
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            oracleConn.Close();
        }
```

When I run the code I get the following error message:

> "ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of
>   arguments in call to 'GETENAME'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL:
>   Statement ignored\n"} System.Exception
>   {System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using a different name for the parameter in your code.  Try changing

```
ename.ParameterName = "ename";
```

to

```
ename.ParameterName = "P_ename";
```

ALSO

You need to add a parameter for the output value:

```
OracleParameter result = new OracleParameter();
result.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
result.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
orclCmnd.Parameters.Add(result);
```

And get the value from the parameter after calling the function with ExecuteNonQuery:

```
orclCmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
strResult = result.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: I tried that and now I get this error "ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00221: 'GETENAME' is not a procedure or is undefined\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored\n"} System.Exception {System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException}"

Comment: D Stanley thank you for ur help. I added the result output parameter and ran the application. I received an error message stating "Parameter 'Parameter 1': No size set for variable length data type: String." So I added result.Size = 1024.  I ran the application again, but I receive the original error message of "wrong number of types"

Comment: Thank you that worked. Still needed to add the result.Size to it.