# calling oracle function from c# giving error

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle10g

When executing a oracle function from C# we are getting this error.
please help to solve.

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
>
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
>   'LIST_WITHOUT_DUBLICATES'
>
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored

My c# code

```
comm.Connection = conn;
comm.CommandText = "LIVE.list_without_dublicates";
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

 comm.Parameters.Add("p_str", to_list);
comm.Parameters.Add("p_sep", ",");
comm.Parameters.Add("result", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
 comm.Parameters["result"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Function signature

```
LIVE.list_without_dublicates(
p_str IN VARCHAR2,
p_sep IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',')
RETURN VARCHAR2
```

Comment: Is the function name really `list_without_dublicates` and not `list_without_duplicates` ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff its `list_without_dublicates` only

Comment: Can you post your function body as well?

Comment: and what is 'to_list' in your c#?

Comment: You're adding parameter result `comm.Parameters.Add("result", OracleDbType.Varchar2)`; and this is not parameter of function.

Comment: @Kacper, yes it is since it's the return value of the function

Comment: Have you tried creating your ReturnValue parameter completely before adding it to the Parameters collection? As in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419722/ora-06550-wrong-number-or-type-of-arguments-error-when-calling-a-function-insid?rq=1

Comment: Is it "@ReturnVal" though, not "result"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210027/calling-stored-procedure-with-return-value. Also, use ExecuteReader if you want some kind of list back

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember you have to specify the (max) length of an `Varchar2` when it is the return value.

Try this one:

```
comm.Parameters.Add("result", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 4000, null, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
```

instead of

```
comm.Parameters.Add("result", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
comm.Parameters["result"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

Also try

```
comm.CommandText = "BEGIN :result := LIVE.list_without_dublicates(:p_str, :p_sep); END;";
comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

instead of

```
comm.CommandText = "LIVE.list_without_dublicates";
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: @Wernfriend thanks for ur answer..it also gave me same error..so i called the funcation with select functionname from dual and it worked..im upvoting ur answer